# collection view cells refresh not happening

Tags: ios, swift, api, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

When view loads I am populating the data from an api call and displaying them to the cells:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    parseData(urll: url)
}
```

When I search from using a search bar I am populating a new set of items using this code:

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    let keywords = searchBar.text
    let finalKey =  keywords?.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "+")
    let finalurl = "https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/search?api_key=0d4f9877de6d4927943adf5a0d20e8a0&q=\(finalKey!)&limit=25&offset=0&rating=G&lang=en"
    parseData(urll: finalurl)
          self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

But when it's loading the new items the old items are not being removed, I've tried using reload data but it didn't work.

And I have reload data function in the `parseData()` function.

`parsedata()` code:

```
 func parseData(urll : String) {
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: urll)!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: .main)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
        }
        else {
            do {
                let fetchedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! NSDictionary
                if  let gifArray = fetchedData.value(forKey: "data") as? NSArray {
                    if  let gifarrayImg = gifArray.value(forKey: "images") as? NSArray {
                        if let gifarrayImgFixedWdth = gifarrayImg.value(forKey: "fixed_width") as? NSArray {
                            for gif in gifarrayImgFixedWdth {
                                if let gifDict = gif as? NSDictionary {
                                    if let imgURL = gifDict.value(forKey: "url") {
                                        print(imgURL)
                                        self.imgUrlArray.append(imgURL as! String)
                                    }
                                    if let imgHeight = gifDict.value(forKey: "height") {
                                        self.height.append(imgHeight as! String)
                                        print(imgHeight)
                                    }
                                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                        self.collectionView.reloadData()
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("Error2")
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

> CollectviewdataSource

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imgUrlArray.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as? CollectionViewCell
    cell?.layer.shouldRasterize = true
    cell?.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale

    let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: URL(string : imgUrlArray[indexPath.row])!, cacheKey: imgUrlArray[indexPath.row])
    cell?.imgview.kf.setImage(with: resource)


    return cell!
}
```

Comment: Please, add the code of parseData() function.

Comment: Is `self.collectionView.reloadData()` being called in parseData()?

Comment: Yes @Dopapp in main Queue

Comment: If reloadData is in fact being called, then your array of data isn’t being changed. Right after your reloadData call, print out the array of your data and verify that it is what you expect

Comment: Can you should your UITableViewDataSource implementation?

Comment: @Dopapp I am getting both the data and its being displayed, but my problem is when call the search function, I want to display only the search results.

Comment: Ah well looking at your searchBarSearchButtonClicked method I see that you always search for finalurl, which is always “www.www” regardless of the searchBar text. finalKey is not used at all

Comment: @Dopapp I had a proper finalUrl in my code , sorry to not show it properly in my question. I guess thats not the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The old items aren't being removed because you are appending the image URLs from the search to the existing imageUrlArray property. So you can remove all the items in that array before you make the search request. Just add this line to the top of your `parsedata()` function:

```
self.imageUrlArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
```

Comment: I implemented it but now I am getting an error of 
fatal error: Index out of range

Comment: I got the solution I need to call the reloadData function again in the search function.